# Error: The getter 'handleFrameworkMessage' isn't defined for the class 'Registrar'

Tags: flutter, error-handling

I am getting this error when I try to launch my app in Chrome, I don't know which package or piece of code is causing it, I haven't used/mentioned Registrar in the whole app.

Error is described below:

```
: Error: The getter 'handleFrameworkMessage' isn't defined for the class 'Registrar'.
- 'Registrar' is from 'package:flutter_web_plugins/src/plugin_registry.dart' ('../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/plugin_registry.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'handleFrameworkMessage'.
    ui.webOnlySetPluginHandler(handleFrameworkMessage);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: The method 'handleFrameworkMessage' isn't defined for the class 'Registrar'.
- 'Registrar' is from 'package:flutter_web_plugins/src/plugin_registry.dart' ('../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/plugin_registry.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'handleFrameworkMessage'.
  ) => handleFrameworkMessage(channel, data, callback);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
`
```

I tried `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get`. also tried to upgrade all the packages with `flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: The error is saying  that  you are trying to use Registrar with with `webOnlySetPluginHandler` but that class lacks of a  `handleFrameworkMessage` getter, so you should add that getter or use another class that has it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.